# swift calculator operation in a switch case

Tags: swift

i am new in programming swift.i have made this code by following other tutorials but i can´t find the correct write typ to perform operation?

```
@IBAction func operation(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let operate = sender.currentTitle!
    switch operate {
    case "+" : performOperation() {}
    case "-" : performOperation() {}
    case "*" : performOperation() {}
    case "/" : performOperation() {}
    default: break
    }

}

func performOperation(operate: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
    }
```

Comment: no, i am not sure, but this is the code from Stanford tutorial so i guess its right. i need to know what i have to insert into the curly brackets to make the operation work

Comment: https://github.com/ursooperduper/calculator/blob/master/Calculator/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`performOperation` method accepts an argument of type `(Double, Double) -> Double`.

Now this argument can be any of the below:

**Method-1.** A closure of type `(Double, Double) -> Double`

**Method-2.** A method name having signature as `(Double, Double) -> Double`

The below example uses both the methods:

```
    func operation()
    {
        let operate = sender.currentTitle!
        switch operate
        {
        case "+" : performOperation(operate: add) //using Method-2
        case "-" : performOperation(){(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double in
            return a - b
        }//using Method-1
        default: break
        }
    }

    func add(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double
    {
        return a + b
    }

    func performOperation(operate: (Double, Double) -> Double)
    {
        let x = operate(3, 4)
        print(x)
    }
```

Similarly, you can use any of the 2 methods for all other `cases` of `switch statement.`